# Is there a wave equation which straightens/rounds the lines between troughs and crests?

Tags: trigonometry, plane-curves, wave-equation

I'm looking for a periodic wave-shape that can transform from something like a sine wave to a zigzag.

I'm particularly interested in:

- the straightening/rounding of the curve between the crests and troughs
  or alternatively
- sharpening/rounding the trough/crests

I am not a well studied mathematician, so a brief explanation of how each variable in such an equation would relate to the desired effect.

I found this equation for a zig zag but there is not rounding that occurs
`y = cos^(-1)(cos(x))`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-C8wsWtdWA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could convolve with a bump function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the family of functions
$$ f_a(x)=\cos^{-1}(a \cos(x) )   $$
When $a= \pm 1$ it is a zigzag

when $-1<a<1$ it is a wave with rounded crests and troughs.

Here is a link to a Desmos file that graphs the functions using a slider for the value of $a$ ...

[Rounding crests](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jmchmznzu1)